# Are small engines on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-definition

Are small engines such as found in many lawn care tools on topic?

- Lawn Mowers (Push and Riding)
- Back pack blowers
- Weed eaters
- Tractors (not so small)

Comment: Forgot about this stack till recently.  I'll have to try some of my chain saw questions here.

Comment: Because we were migrating so many of these to Gardening, an [area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55551/small-engine-repair-and-maintenence) just got created.

Answer (score 13):

I would say yes, for two reasons,

1. There is no Small Engines stack exchange, or similar site that would be more appropriate for these questions.
2. I would assume, at least from personal experience, that those who know car repair or small engine repair are likely to have knowledge of both subjects, with a smaller percent having interest in both.

Comment: There is a new proposal on Area51 for a [Small engine repair and maintenance stack](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55551/small-engine-repair-and-maintenance)

Answer (score 9):

I suspect the *lack* of response here is due to total indifference to the *subject*. There used to be a *Small Engine Maintenance* proposal which was abandoned and purged due to lack of interest. Further, there are no questions on this site about small engines, nor does anyone seem interested in asking them.

In the interest of **encouraging future input**, we can leave this subject open to further posts.

I would suggest, in the meantime, that **small engines are (tentatively) on topic**, leaving the site at least *amenable* to such subjects.

When we have actual evidence (and examples) of what type of small-engine questions people might want to ask here, we can have a more concrete discussion about the topic.

Comment: I don't feel that this is on-topic, however I like this approach better than just slamming the door on the subject all together.

Comment: @Larry: This isn't to single you out, specifically, but where is the rest of the community? It doesn't reflect well on a site when such a basic meta question goes without response for so long. This is right out [The 7 Essential Meta Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

Comment: **Agreed** I didn't reply when I first read it because I didn't want to slam the door, and I wanted to see some other peoples input first. It seems that we don't have much participation in meta at all, and only a few active people answering questions on the main site.

Comment: @Larry: that's a noble motivation there, but... *You're part of the community* - if you see a question like this where you have an opinion, state it; if nothing else, this gives others who feel differently a PoV to respond to, and those who agree a statement to refine or coalesce around.

Answer (score 2):

I feel better about tractors and lawn mowers than I do about weed eaters and blowers.  You can at least make the (perhaps silly) argument that they're motorized vehicles.  Hey, and there are races for both.

Answer (score 1):

There is a proposal on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) for a [Small engine repair and maintenance](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55551/small-engine-repair-and-maintenance) site.  If small engines are not on topic here, questions can be migrated to the small engine site (if it gets enough of a following, and actually becomes a site). If small engines are on topic, this site can absorb the small engines site.