# Is tractor maintenance on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

There's a related meta question ([Are small engines on topic?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/are-small-engines-on-topic)), but that's more about *small engines*.

How about questions on maintenance of compact tractors (not lawn tractors -- I'm thinking about >20-25HP diesel tractors with 3ph, hydraulics, pto)?

- hydraulics
- suitability of attachments

  - power requirements
  - making alterations/adapting to fit an attachment

Specifically, I'd like to ask (with a few details added in the real question):

> **How can I more quickly switch between the lift and the attachment?**
>
> I've got a wood splitter that mounts on the three point hitch and runs off the rear hydraulic take-off.
>
> [photo of hyd pipes/fittings]
>
> In order to raise/lower (i.e. to move the machine) I have to shut off the tractor and swap hoses. I know that I should be able to add a valve, but I'm not sure of the right approach to take.
>
> What sort of valve do I need to add, and what's the right approach to take for piping and mounting?
>
> [tractor](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tractor) [hydraulic](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydraulic)

Answer (score 16):

I'm on the fence, but I lean toward allowing the question.

Hydraulics was a required class included in my Automotive/Diesel Degree, mainly because diesel technicians that work on heavy equipment also repair the hydraulics associated with them.

In the spirit of growing the community I say post the question, if the community doesn't agree we can certainly discuss it here.

Just a note for newish users voting works a little different on meta. You up-vote if you agree with the poster, down-vote if you disagree.

Comment: Thanks Larry. I'll take a couple of pictures and post the question tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: @bstpierre In case I don't see it when you do, post a comment to your question linking to this meta question

Comment: Will do. (15 characters)

Comment: If this is community consensus, them the Help pages should be updated to include the larger equipment like tractors and riding lawnmowers. Though the site is titled *"Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair"*, the [help pages](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) only includes language for *"... cars, trucks, and motorcycles"*. (My riding lawnmower is bigger than the my first motorcycle. And I have seen folks get a DUI on riding lawnmowers, just like a car or motorcycle).

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion, Tractors are motor vehicles, and therefore should be allowed. Hydraulics in principle are an essential part of all motor vehicles (brakes, for example), even if most don't have to deal with valves etc.

Comment: If this is community consensus, them the Help pages should be updated to include the larger equipment like tractors and riding lawnmowers. Though the site is titled *"Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair"*, the [help pages](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) only includes language for *"... cars, trucks, and motorcycles"*. (My riding lawnmower is bigger than the my first motorcycle. And I have seen folks get a DUI on riding lawnmowers, just like a car or motorcycle).