# Would the community welcome questions on Small engine repair and maintenance

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope

There is an Area 51 Proposal for [Small engine repair and maintenance](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55551/small-engine-repair-and-maintenance?referrer=JxcRVskuqOf6biNthqvlIQ2)

I feel like the the questions currently listed would be on topic here.

- I left gas in my Toro mower over the winter, how do I get it started?
- Will Ethanol damage my small engine?
- How do I install a new Briggs and Stratton fuel filter on my riding mower?
- How do I prepare my snow blower for summer storage?
- My lawnmower starts, but then sputters and dies, what's the problem and how do I solve it?
- When is it time to replace my spark plug?
- How do I clean the carburetor on my Briggs and Stratton lawn mower?
- How do I free up the choke on my 93 Honda FourTrax 300 ATV?
- Will spray carburetor cleaner damage my Briggs and Stratton carburetor's plastic parts?
- How do I change the oil (in my push lawnmower) without making a mess? Do I have to drain the gas tank first?

Here are discussions we have already had on meta

[Is tractor maintenance on-topic?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/118/85)

[Are small engines on topic?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/83/85)

Something to consider; we are still trying to attract experts in the automotive repair field, which is an entirely different discussion, but will having these questions make automotive experts less likely to frequent the site?

Comment: Another question comes to mind, that I am not sure would be welcome here. What about electric lawnmowers, weedeaters, chainsaws etc.

Comment: "***motor*** vehicle" would suggest that motors are as on topic as engines, as long as they are part of a vehicle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are small engines on topic?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/83/38280)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I this is covered squarely by the second paragraph in the FAQ:

> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and
>   their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications
>   other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or
>   engine accessories.

I think that, based on that paragraph, most of your example questions are already covered by our topic area.

You can also easily see that some specific problems (e.g., winterizing) could easily apply to a vehicle (e.g., track day car) as well as a lawnmower.

Comment: Agreed. I don't know a single professional automotive technician that would not repair his own lawnmower, weedeater, etc.

Comment: Seconded. An engine is an engine, regardless of whether it is in a Car, Lawnmower, Boat, Aircraft etc. Small two-strokes are pretty similar to scooter engines which are definitely on-topic after all... I can't imagine the volume of such questions would overwhelm the site. The ATV question is definitely on-topic, as that's a motor vehicle!